Eclispse Store & Wildfly Cluster / Infinispan
I am looking into suggestions how to set up a wildfly cluster running with Eclipse Store as a "backend".
There is a working example for (single-node) wildfly, but my problem is how to use the store in a distributed way - I want some kind of failover capacity in case a server fails.
The documentation of the store reads:
At any given time, only one JVM process may directly access the files representing a unique set of data. Such a restriction is crucial for the correct execution of any application: changes to an application’s persistent data have to be guarded by the rules of the application’s business logic, i.e. the process that currently runs the application. Allowing another process to bypass these rules would eventually result in catastrophic consistency errors.
The requirement to distribute an application over multiple processes must be solved by a clustering approach (e.g. by distributing logic AND persistent data over multiple processes or by having one process to serve as the data master for multiple worker processes).
Is it possible to combine it with infinispan (P2P,...) in an "easy way"?
Thanks.
